# Enable load movie button event on other flash movie

Tags: flash, load, movie

In my flash movie I load another flash movie with button on it. The problem is when I trigger the button the event on the load flash not function. When I check the button it trigger event trough root function on the parent clip. How I can enable the button event on the load movie when I load it on my flash movie?

Answer (score 0):

which version of actionscript are you using ?

If you're using as2.0 
use the MovieClipLoader class to load your swf and try to access your button in the [onLoadInit](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=Part4_ASLR2.html) event handler.

If you're using as3.0, again...try to access your button in the [Event.INIT](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#INIT) hander of your Loader instance. Remember that in as3 you ad you listener to the contentLoaderInfo property of your Loader, not directly to the Loader instance.

The init event is triggered once your swf has been load **and** the classes/instances inside have been initialized, so you should be able to access them then.

Goodluck!